# How to make a Image visible on a particular row in a Listview generated using SimpleAdapter?

Tags: android, android-listview, simpleadapter

I am trying to set an `Imageview` visible only on particular rows in a `Listview` which is generated using a `Simpleadapter`. I want to make an ImageView visible only on selected rows of the ListView i.e 2 and 4 when that particular row is clicked. I am getting the position from the onItemClickListener. I just want to know how to set it at a particular row. I want to continue with SimpleAdapter itself. Can any one guide me step by step what to do?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an entity class to define getter and setters for variables. now define a variable showHide image and generate its getter and setter.
Now in coustom arrayAdapter in getview method add condition

```
if(getShowHide(){
Image.setVisibility(View.Visible);
}
else{
Image.setVisibility(View.Gone);
}
```

Now `onitem click` set `ShowHide` to true for that position and call notify `datasetchanged()` on adapter.